# Change PDF engine for Email Attachments by Fooman

Tags: magento-1.9, email, overrides, pdf

I'm using Firegento as PDF engine for invoice, etc (as part of Magento DE). Fooman's Email Attachments takes the standard Zend engine. Is it possible to change the setting to take the Firegento engine instead so the order PDF looks the same like invoice, shipping list, etc.

Comment: sounds tricky, but I'm sure you could achieve this by fiddling around with the `config.xml` files of each modules, but I'm pretty sure that'd screw up one process or another at some point.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is currently no setting or provision for this. If anyone wants to contribute such feature please see the [github repository](https://github.com/fooman/emailattachments).

Answer (score 0):

FireGento_Pdf is implemented in a way that the defined engine is used everywhere in Magento. Basically it overrides the classes which are responsible for the PDF creation so that the correct engine is used. Fooman_EmailAttachments should therefore definitely also use the FireGento engine - I also use both of these extensions in different shops and the correct engine is used in each of them.

If this does not work for you, check if you use the latest versions of these extensions and check if there are any rewrite conflicts. The two mentioned extensions normally do not have any conflicts, but there may be a third extension which makes some problems.